# how can I implement redux in server-side react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux, server-side-rendering

I am trying to stuff the authentication info into the redux store so header can connect and get the info. I am using google oauth with passport.js.

```
//this is controller
exports.currentUser = (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
};

//this is the route
const authCtrl = require("../controllers/authCtrl");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/current_user", authCtrl.currentUser);
```

this is how I set up the router for express

```
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/authRoutes"));
```

here is the auth reducer:

```
import { FETCH_USER } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = { _id: null, googleId: null, displayName: "" };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

this is the action for getting the current user:

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
  timeout: 3000,
});

import { FETCH_USER, FETCH_BLOGS, FETCH_BLOG } from "./types";

export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get("/auth/current_user");

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

this is the client-side store:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
});

//we are passing axiosInstance to all action creators
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  window.INITIAL_STATE,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(axiosInstance))
);
```

so far so good. but the problem is creating the server side store: I did this but not working:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "../client/reducers";

export default (req) => {
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
  console.log("store from servre", store);
  return store;
};
```

in this case reducer is not returning the state. I could not figure out the issue all day. hope soneone is going to reply